# INPayBillIntentHandling does not call required protocol methods when there is more than one bill payment application is installed

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

I am trying to implement a bill payment extension via Siri. In the extension user only specifies the bill type and after the input, he/she will be directed to application and needs to login. Everything works fine if there is only my application that supports bill payment, is installed in the device. Even applications supporting money send via Siri can lead to unwanted behavior. Another finding in the issue is, if the device OS version is between 10.3 and 11 this issue is encountered. However, in iOS 11 v6 this issue seems to be fixed.

**Problem:** Almost always Siri does not enter the method `handle(intent:completion:)` which is the required INPayBillIntentHandling protocol method. Extension only asks for type of the bill, enters resolve protocol methods and enters the optional protocol method `confirm(intent:completion:)`. In the end it needs to enter handle method but it does not enter the method. After opening the main application via Siri, AppDelegate's `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` method does not called either.

**Edit:** I have one other Siri extension(Send Payment) that functioning properly.

Codes are given below..

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.3, *)
class PayBillIntentHandler: NSObject, INPayBillIntentHandling {

public func handle(payBill intent: INPayBillIntent, completion: @escaping (INPayBillIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    completion(INPayBillIntentResponse(
        code: .inProgress,
        userActivity: process(intent: intent)))
    }

func confirm(payBill intent: INPayBillIntent, completion: @escaping (INPayBillIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    let userActivity = process(intent: intent)
    let success = (userActivity != nil)
    let code: INPayBillIntentResponseCode = success ? .success : .failureInsufficientFunds
        let response = INPayBillIntentResponse(code: code, userActivity: userActivity)
        response.billDetails = INBillDetails(billType: intent.billType,
                                             paymentStatus: .unpaid,
                                             billPayee: nil,
                                             amountDue: nil,
                                             minimumDue: nil,
                                             lateFee: nil,
                                             dueDate: nil,
                                             paymentDate: nil)

    completion(response)
    }

func resolveBillType(forPayBill intent: INPayBillIntent,
                     with completion: @escaping (INBillTypeResolutionResult) -> Void) {

       if intent.billType != .unknown {
           completion(INBillTypeResolutionResult.success(with: intent.billType))
       } else {
           completion(INBillTypeResolutionResult.needsValue())
       }
    }

@discardableResult fileprivate func process(intent: INPayBillIntent) -> NSUserActivity? {

        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: String(describing: INPayBillIntent.self))
        var properties = [String: Any]()

        properties["billType"] = billType: intent.billType.rawValue
        userActivity.userInfo = ["properties": properties]
    }
}
```